# Why can't I add tasks to the thread pool the second time in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I create a thread pool to deal with the task, after deal with the task,I find I can not add and start the other task? How to fix it? If I change the executor by `executor =   new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new NamedThreadFactory("timeOutThread"));` ,It will run OK.But if the task is canceled because of timeout,do this will cause memory leak?

```
ExecutorService executor =   new ThreadPoolExecutor(3,
                    3, 0L,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1),
                    new NamedThreadFactory(
                            "timeOutThread")); 
    List<Callable<String>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(index -> {
        callableList.add(() -> request(index));
    });
    List<Future<String>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(callableList, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
            Future<String> future = futureList.get(i);
            try {
                list.add(future.get());
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                log.info("timeOut task：{}", i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
          Thread.sleep(1000);
    callableList.clear();
    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(index -> {
        callableList.add(() -> request(index));
    });
      long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
     // Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5fdcaa40 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6dc17b83   
    List<Future<String>> futureList   = executor.invokeAll(callableList, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        Future<String> future = futureList.get(i);
        try {
            list.add(future.get());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            log.info("timeOut Task：{}", i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

  public String request() throws InterruptedException { 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200000);
    return "A";
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1)`, i.e., a queue of capacity 1 is causing you trouble?

Comment: @akarnokd,If `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1)` cause the problem ,I wonder why the first time execution is OK

Comment: My guess: When you first call `invokeAll`, none of the core threads have been started yet. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class is, if I recall correctly, implemented to always start a new core thread if the set number of core threads has not been reached yet. In that case, the task is handed to the thread and the queue is bypassed. But the _second_ time you call `invokeAll`, all the core threads have been started. So now the tasks are added to the queue. Your queue has a capacity of one, but you're adding three tasks all at once.

Comment: @Slaw,at first time the core thread have deal with  3 task beacuse of timeout,why the second time,this core thread can do nothing?

Comment: You've created a thread pool with three core threads. You submit three tasks at once. The first time, each task results in one of the three core threads being started (i.e., each task is mapped to its own thread). The second time, those threads are already started, and therefore there's an attempt to add the tasks to the queue. But the queue is too small.

Comment: @akarnokd,ThreadPoolExecutor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true)  is not work.it only have method like setRejectedExecutionHandler,setCorePoolSize

Comment: My bad, that method is on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor; you probably don't need it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow,I have change the title,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with the following simplified code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        3, 3, 0L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1));
    try {
      System.out.println("Executing first batch of tasks...");
      submitTasks(pool);

      System.out.println("Executing second batch of tasks...");
      submitTasks(pool);
    } finally {
      pool.shutdown();
    }
  }

  private static void submitTasks(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
    var tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      tasks.add(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(2_000L);
        return null;
      });
    }
    executor.invokeAll(tasks);
  }
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
Executing first batch of tasks...
Executing second batch of tasks...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@87aac27[Not completed, task = Main$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800c009f0@816f27d] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3e3abc88[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2070)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:833)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1365)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(AbstractExecutorService.java:247)
        at Main.submitTasks(Main.java:32)
        at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

The problem is caused by the queue being too small. The `LinkedBlockingQueue` is created with a capacity of only one, but three tasks are submitted to the pool at once. So, the question becomes, why does it only fail on the second call to `invokeAll`?

The reason has to do with how `ThreadPoolExecutor` is implemented. When an instance is first created, none of the core threads are started. They are started lazily as tasks are submitted. When the submission of a task results in a thread being started, that task is immediately given to the thread. The queue is bypassed. So, when `invokeAll` is called the first time, each of the three core threads is started and none of the tasks go into the queue.

But the second time `invokeAll` is called, the core threads have already been started. Since submitting the tasks does *not* result in a thread being created, the tasks are put into the queue. But the queue is too small, resulting in the `RejectedExecutionException`. If you're wondering why the core threads are still alive despite the keep-alive time being set to zero, that's because core threads are not allowed to die due to timeout by default (you have to explicitly configure the pool to allow that).

You can see this lazily-started-core-threads is the cause of the problem by modifying the code slightly. Simply adding:

```java
pool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
```

Just after creating the pool causes the **first call** to `invokeAll` to now fail with a `RejectedExecutionException`.

Also, if you change the queue's capacity from one to three, then the `RejectedExecutionException` will no longer occur.

---

Here's some relevant [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Any `BlockingQueue` may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> - If fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are running, the `Executor` always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If `corePoolSize` or more threads are running, the `Executor` always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed `maximumPoolSize`, in which case, the task will be rejected.

Comment: Why pool.prestartAllCoreThreads(); first call can cause RejectedExecutionException?If `change the queue's capacity from one to three, then the RejectedExecutionException will no longer occur`.When did the core thread to deal with the task? In my opinion, the core thread  should  process task  immediately if it is created.But in fact, the opposite is true.After first time call,the three core thread is already deal with the three task,and wait to deal with the coming task.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you're confused. The queue is only bypassed **if submitting the task results in a thread being created**. Otherwise, the task ends up in the queue, even if there's a pool thread ready to pull the task out of the queue immediately. By increasing the queue's capacity, you allow more than one task to be queued at a time. Note it _takes time_ for a pool thread blocking on the queue to wake up, acquire the necessary lock, and grab the task from the queue. In that time, the thread which called `invokeAll` has tried to add too many tasks to the queue.

Comment: "_In my opinion, the core thread should process task immediately if it is created_" – But as I explained, that's exactly what happens. When the thread is **created** the task is processed immediately, without going into the queue. That's why the first call to `invokeAll` succeeds. But during the second call to `invokeAll`, **no thread is _created_** because all core threads have **already been created**. "_After first time call,the three core thread is already deal with the three task,and wait to deal with the coming task._" – What else are the already-created threads supposed to do?

Comment: Note that, fundamentally, and ignoring the execute-task-immediately-upon-creation functionality, what a pool thread does is `while (!shutdown) { Runnable task = queue.take(); task.run(); }`.