# ThreadPoolExecutor Rejected Execution Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I created the following executor using ThreadPoolExecutor

```
        try {

            GZIPInputStream gzipIS = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("filePath"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzipIS, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                executor.execute(new ParallelScan(line));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("\nException == " + e);
        }
```

```
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            4, 10, 10000000, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1));
```

Max pool size as 10. But still it's failing when active threads count is 0. It is failing with below error

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@33990a0c[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 23]
```

There are two reasons why execute would throw a RejectedExecutionException
1.

1. The queue is full and you cannot add any more threads
2. The ThreadPool has been shut down

But it's not the case in my scenario. Neither queue is full nor ThreadPool has been shut down.

What could be the reason for above error.

Comment: You're using an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a capacity of `1`. My guess is that if you add enough tasks fast enough, the queue is actually reaching capacity after the maximum number of threads have been created (thus no new thread can be started to take pressure off the queue). In other words, something [similar to the problem in this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72701282/6395627).